# Very high fan speed on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, fan, fancontrol

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04, alongside Windows 10. On Ubuntu, one of my fans is extremely high, although the temperature is fine, and this is not happening on Windows. I've tried some of the solutions suggested in this forum, without success.

The one with the problem seems to be nct6775/fan2, at least it is the only one working at +1155 rpm, according to program HardInfo. My motherboard is an ASUS H81M-A.

Comment: What steps have you taken to address the fans specifically?  Is `fancontrol` running?  What does your `/etc/fancontrol` file look like?

Comment: If you have an Intel CPU, try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/516067/persistent-high-fan-speed-ubuntu-14-04/1033903#1033903

Comment: Try plugging the fan in a SYS fan header instead of a CPU header. For some motherboards I found out that the fan will try running at a higher speed than normal, and some CPU fans when plugged into the SYS header runs at a lower speed. Worth the shot though

Answer (score 15):

The typical steps for fancontrol setup include:

- Running `sensors-detect` to ensure you have the correct modules and updates `/etc/modules` (`/etc/sysconfig/lm_sensors` on RH) to have the nct6775 entry.
- Running `pwmconfig` to test and configure each fan and creates the `/etc/fancontrol` file.

There are known issues where sometimes the hwmon ids change between boots, leaving your fans out of control.  For that you would manually edit your `/etc/fancontrol` file to include the full path of each pwm and replace the id with `[[:print:]]*` like so:  `/sys/devices/platform/nct6775.656/hwmon/hwmon[[:print:]]*/pwm1`

These are actual paths on the files system that you can browse to get an idea of what is available.

You may also need to edit `/etc/sensors3.conf`, I had to add some stuff for the ASUS Z97, I posted those details on [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021375/controlling-fan-headers-on-an-asus-maximus-viii-formula/1021385#1021385).

You may also need to add the following to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` variable in the `/etc/default/grub` file: `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` then rebuild the grub config `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll check this out. I've already installed lm-sensors and fancontrol. In pwmconfig, during the tests, my fan doesn't stop at all. I'll go over it again.

Comment: Did this work fine in Ubuntu 16?  I don't have any control over my 3pin fans, only the 4pin ones.  Most of my noise comes from the GPU fan.  If you can see that it is fan2, you should be able to control it.  Take a look at the filesystem, all fancontrol does is read/write the  files in `/sys/devices/platform/nct6775.656/hwmon/hwmon3/`.  Also lsmod and make sure nct6775 is loaded..and make sure your ASUS is using that chip (likely is).

Comment: I have not installed any other version of Ubuntu in that PC, so I can't tell. I'll check what you suggest. Thankx!

Answer (score 8):

I struggled with fan speed and thermal issues for a long time before I found `tlp` which has solved all my problems. You can learn more [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TLP):

> TLP brings you the benefits of advanced power management for Linux
>   without the need to understand every technical detail. TLP comes with
>   a default configuration already optimized for battery life, so you may
>   just install and forget it. Nevertheless TLP is highly customizable to
>   fulfill your specific requirements.

Installation is the predictable

```
sudo apt install tlp
```

Configuration is automatic and I've never had to change it out of the box.

---

If `tlp` by itself doesn't solve all your thermal issues there are specific steps you can take for [ASUS Laptops](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fan_speed_control#Asus_laptops):

#### Kernel modules overview

- `asus-nb-wmi` is a kernel module, which is included in mainstream Linux kernel and is loaded automatically in Asus laptops. It will only allow to control a single fan and if there is a second fan - you will not have any controls over it. Blacklisting this module will prevent keyboard backlight to work.
- `asus_fan` is a kernel module, which allows to control both fans on some older Asus laptops. Does not work with the most recent models.

For myself after installing `tlp` I was able to remove a couple of fan control programs I had struggled to setup for my laptop. However I do not have an ASUS so you might need something more than just `tlp`.

Comment: And my laptop turns out to be Asus.

Answer (score 6):

I was having problems with Ubuntu 18.04 on my Asus laptop Q551L and high fan speed when coming out of sleep. My laptop had nvidia devices needing drivers including my video card GM108M GeForce 840M.
Here's what fixed it for me as explained on [this page](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux).

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Then reboot.

Comment: I think it is the reboot that works for this answer

Comment: Suspending and then waking my laptop was enough to stop the fan noise

Answer (score 2):

There can be two things at play here and for that there are two things you can do/try.

## 1. Check BIOS settings.

certain settings can be found/only be found in the BIOS, one of these settings that can be found in the BIOS are the fan settings, you can check here if there is something wrong there.

## 2. Sensor broke

It is possible that the sensor of the fan might have broken, i know there is away to check that with a GUI with Ubuntu and Windows so i will explain both.

#### Ubuntu

To check your sensor with Ubuntu you need to have `hardinfo` installed you do this by using the command `sudo apt-get install hardinfo` with this you can see if the sensor is okay or broken.

#### Windows

To check your sensor with Windows you will need to install Speedfan which can be found [here](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php). it will show you the temperatures your fansensors are reading and the speed of your fans
(side note: it has been a while since i used these programs so they might be different then i remember them)

i hope this will solve your problem cause it did for me

Comment: Hello, friend. I think yours is more a comment than an answer. Plus, it shows you did not read my question properly. Please, post it as a comment instead.

Comment: @estebanknobl i would do so if i could since commenting is only available with a rep of 50, but i forgot about a third option which is highly doubt-able but possible and that is it is wrongly wired, should i add this to the answer as well?

Comment: @estebanknobl secondly 'I've tried some of the solutions suggested in this forum' isn't very clear on what you have tried i mean you might have missed one of the two i mentioned (as i missed/blanked on the part of 'hardinfo' (yes i have memory problems))

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues as @sef. I have a Lenovo laptop with Geforce MX150, running ubuntu 20. To fix my noisy fan I also had to:

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

but in addition I also had to go to "nvidia x server settings", and set "PRIME Profiles" to "NVIDIA on demand", reboot. If I now open "Thermal settings in the same program, I can see lower gpu temperatures. In the PowerMizer I can now see that performance level 0 is being used. I used to always be on a higher level (performance).

Answer (score 0):

fan speed can be monitored from bios.
try to change the settings there to "silent mode" in Q-fan configuration.
to get there you can use this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wMrCsFxLTQ&t=58s

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem after replacing the motherboard. I finally found that I had forgotten to reconnect the sensor cable to the new motherboard. The sensor cable is small 4 pin plug. The socket for it is located on the right-front side of the board (looking at the front of the computer). It's very easy to overlook connecting it. My computer ran very quit as soon as the sensor was reconnected.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with my `Asus BM6820` desktop & `Nvidia GeForce GT 730`.
I've tried all of the tips above but finally found. The problem was the kernel's stock Nvidia driver: `nouveau` caused the problem.

Boot your pc to init 3 runlevel to verify this problem. If the fan speed is OK, you can try to disable nvidia nouveau driver.

How to disable Nouveau nvidia driver:

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-nouveau-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

```
$ sudo bash -c "echo blacklist nouveau > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf"
$ sudo bash -c "echo options nouveau modeset=0 >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf"
```

Confirm the content of the new modprobe config file:

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

Then install the proper Nvidia driver from Nvidia's site:

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Answer (score 0):

My laptop was fairly new, and I wasn't running much with load of 2.
With 8 CPU cores and an i7, I knew something was wrong.

I resolved this issue by using tlp .

```
lspci -v | perl -ne '/VGA/../^$/ and /VGA|Kern/ and print'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
systemctl enable tlp # to enable on startup
vim /etc/default/tlp
```

You should have something like this.

```
tlp-stat -c
--- TLP 1.2.2 --------------------------------------------

+++ Configured Settings: /etc/default/tlp
        TLP_ENABLE=1
        TLP_DEFAULT_MODE=AC
        TLP_PERSISTENT_DEFAULT=0
        DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_AC=0
        DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_BAT=2
        MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_AC=15
        MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_BAT=60
        CPU_HWP_ON_AC=balance_performance
        CPU_HWP_ON_BAT=balance_power
        CPU_MAX_PERF_ON_AC=100
        CPU_BOOST_ON_AC=1
        SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_AC=0
        SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_BAT=1
        NMI_WATCHDOG=0
        ENERGY_PERF_POLICY_ON_AC=performance
        ENERGY_PERF_POLICY_ON_BAT=power
        DISK_DEVICES="nvme0n1 sda"
        DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_AC="254 254"
        DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_BAT="128 128"
        SATA_LINKPWR_ON_AC="med_power_with_dipm max_performance"
        SATA_LINKPWR_ON_BAT="med_power_with_dipm min_power"
        AHCI_RUNTIME_PM_TIMEOUT=15
        WIFI_PWR_ON_AC=off
        WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT=on
        WOL_DISABLE=Y
        SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_AC=0
        SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT=1
        SOUND_POWER_SAVE_CONTROLLER=Y
        BAY_POWEROFF_ON_AC=0
        BAY_POWEROFF_ON_BAT=0
        BAY_DEVICE="sr0"
        RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC=on
        RUNTIME_PM_ON_BAT=auto
        USB_AUTOSUSPEND=1
        USB_BLACKLIST_BTUSB=0
        USB_BLACKLIST_PHONE=0
        USB_BLACKLIST_PRINTER=1
        USB_BLACKLIST_WWAN=0
        RESTORE_DEVICE_STATE_ON_STARTUP=0
        NATACPI_ENABLE=1
        TPACPI_ENABLE=1
        TPSMAPI_ENABLE=1
```

In my case I use Intel, so I disabled Radeon.
reboot, super annoying fan noise gone.

Answer (score 0):

For me, It has been solved running the following:

```
sudo apt install smbios-utils
sudo smbios-thermal-ctl -v --set-thermal-mode=quiet
```

Comment: what hardware did this work on, please?