# ASUS Fan Control

Tags: drivers, asus, cpu, overheating, fan

First, I am well aware of the numerous other posts, all of which I have read through many times, trying each of their solutions and variants of it, so please do not flag as duplicate or post links to them, I have seen them.

I believe this is more of a kernel issue (tried on both 4.16 and 4.17) more than a Ubuntu issue, as the same occurred on Arch when I was running that.

I have a relatively new ASUS FX503VM, which utilizes 2 CPU fans. It is detected as:

```
asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:       0 RPM
```

And 0 is where it stays, and is always detected as. I have altered the div to various values including 4, 8, 16, 32, 128, etc, etc. Always 0, once in a while will be -1 after experimenting with various driver settings. The fan does not run, and all 4 cores are staying close to 60C, which is not cool, no pun intended. If the temps climb too high the, the BIOS kick in and run the fans to keep them from melting, but that's it. My BIOS do not have settings to adjust threshold, unfortunately.

I have tried the following:

- `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` as a boot parameter
- `ncfs` does nothing, just a different method of failing to read RPM
- `nct6775` driver
- `asus_fan` (though I can't get `modprobe` to ever work, so I am unsure
  on the possible success of this option...)(I added to modules, did
  not get any reported errors, but it changed nothing)
- `pwmconfig` is of no help, as it skips after trying to run the fan
  and nothing changes.
- Flashed my BIOS to the newest available version (April, 2018)
- Took control of the CPU governor with `thermald`, which helped to
  reduce temps about 10C, but does not solve the problem. I want the
  fans to run, not throttle back the CPU
- Confirmed fans work, and RPM sensors work as I can see as much in the
  BIOS

I am at the end of the line of things to try, and am becoming more and more certain this is issue that cannot be solved with anything, basically just have incompatible hardware to run Linux. Does anyone have a solution I am missing, or have a ASUS FX503VM that can either confirm or deny that the CPU fans work as expected with this model?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032109/very-high-fan-speed-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: @RomaPromy That is a slightly different problem, though one of the solutions for that particular problem were one of the things I have already tried and listed above. After researching since this question, it appears that there is no great solution for the current kernel and motherboard of my PC, and will just have to wait for support to be added.

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/a/1223873/50254