# Fan issues with Asus GL753VD with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, asus, fan

I have a laptop Asus ROG GL753VD that I have partitioned, it has Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.

Everything works fine, keyboard, screen, wifi etc. but there is an odd behavior with the fan, sometimes it does not start and thus the computer gets very hot.

This laptop has the "Optimus" technology (2 video cards Intel + Nvidia)

I already installed the lm-sensors

```
iwlwifi-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +37.0°C  

pch_skylake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +54.0°C  

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +42.0°C  (crit = +98.0°C)

asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:        0 RPM

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +41.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +40.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +40.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +41.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +40.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

The workaround that I found is that I switch to the Nvidia card until the temperature is 80 and then I switch back to Intel, that way the fan starts working, I tried multiple times to manually make the fan to start (non-working example below)

```
find /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon*/ -name "fan*"

/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/fan1_input
/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/fan1_label
sudo echo "255" > /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/pwm1
```

I also tried with fancontrol but it doesn't work

```
donhk@GL753VD:~$ sudo systemctl status fancontrol
● fancontrol.service - fan speed regulator
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fancontrol.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
Condition: start condition failed at Sun 2018-10-14 09:33:51 CDT; 33min ago
           └─ ConditionPathExists=/etc/fancontrol was not met
     Docs: man:fancontrol(8)
           man:pwmconfig(8)
```

my question is

since the fan starts automatically after a switch between cards, would it be possible to detect what is making the fan to start to create a script?

[nvidia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDMOf.png)

Comment: Can you try 'echo 255 | sudo tee /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/pwm1' and/or 'sudo touch /etc/fancontrol' ?

Comment: tried already, it does not turn the fan on, for now, the only working thing is the warm-up workaround to force the fan to start due to critic temp reached

Comment: Maybe [a duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032109/very-high-fan-speed-on-ubuntu-18-04)?

Comment: no, that problem is different, I already checked that question :)