# What could be causing constant fan noise on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, dell, system, fancontrol

I have a lot of fan noise on ubuntu 16.04 on a new Dell laptop.

I can't tell what's happening from the graphics card or any software program. The fan is working and never stops. My friend has the same computer and doesn't have this issue. They shut down after cooling the fan.

I talked with customer service and they say it's not a hardware problem.

How can I find out what's causing this problem?

If I run `sensors` just after logging in I get this:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +25.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +49.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +49.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +47.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +48.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +47.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
Processor Fan: 3797 RPM
CPU:            +51.0°C  
Ambient:        +43.0°C  
SODIMM:         +44.0°C  
Other:          +47.0°C
```

Comment: Try to run the `sensors` command in a terminal window to check the temperatures. Add the output to the question.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: You might also want to check the running processes with `top` or `htop`, or with the device manager. Fan speed depends a lot on what's running at a given moment. If the machine is idle, the fan probably has no business to run at 3800RPM, but if not, perhaps it does. You've posted a rather vague question here, so just trying to guess and fill in the blanks.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032109/very-high-fan-speed-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix It's a Dell Laptop.  It may require i8kutils to manage the fans.