# Overheating and Fast Fan with Ubuntu 18.04 on Asus X550VX

Tags: drivers, nvidia, overheating, fan, temperature

My notebook (with NVIDIA) is running in abnormally fast fan speed and temp. At first I thought it was the graphic card, then I installed appropriate drivers for my graphic card, still having the same issue. I came across [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032109/very-high-fan-speed-on-ubuntu-18-04?) about the same issue. I followed the instruction to

- instal `sensor-detect`
- `pwmconfig` to test each fan
- /etc/fancontrol to create file
- add parameter `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` (I also put `pci=nomsi` and `pci=noaer` already)
- disable turbo boost

However, after booting a few times, my notebook still running at crazy temperature. I tried to run `sensors` and this is the result :

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +54.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +51.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +53.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +51.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +52.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

I literally can hear the fans running super fast, sometimes randomly when I'm not even running anything (idle). I just recently switched to Ubuntu and and still trying to figure this out. Any advice on how I can overcome this issue ?

Comment: Depending on ambient temperature, those temperatures could be perfectly reasonable. At least they are far from abnormal. The fans running when you _think_ the computer is idle could be due to something running in the background, e.g. unattended upgrades.

Comment: The steps from that question generally do not work with laptops.  53C is normal for a laptop.  When running sensors-detect, does it detect a SuperIO chip but says its unknown?

Comment: @rtaft in the end the result is just coretemp. No SuperIO detected. Also while 53 sounds normal, as I said in my question I can hear the fan sound crystal clear which makes me worried.