# MSI x570 A Pro fan speed and CPU temps are high on ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, cpu, fan, temperature, msi

This is the system i have:

> MB: MSI x570 A PRO
> CPU: AMD 3600 (No OC)
> RAM: 32 GB with X-AMP enabled for 3200MHz (as per specs)
> PSU: 650W Corsair
> CPU Colling: Noctua NH-U12S chromax.black
> Running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
> Linux version 5.3.0-62-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-004) (gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)) #56~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 24 16:17:03 UTC 2020

(if anything more is relevant i will make sure to include it here)
So i've always wanted to go to Ubuntu but my work **required** Windows and now i'm able to use Ubuntu on a daily basis but i've had some issues from the start with the system.
The only things that are bothering me is that with a aftermarket cooler Noctua which is rated around 120-150W the CPU is spiking from 40 C to 60-70 without anything running on the bg or foreground and the reason i know its at that temp is because from the BIOS i've set the fans to ramp up when above 60 C. (The thermal paste is covering the cpu nicely without any air pockets)
The other thing that i couldn't find is how can i control my fans from the OS. In the BIOS i have to set them as DC not PWM (with PWM they are at 100% all the time no idea why) and they are not visible trough sensors-detect or any other suggestions here [Very high fan speed on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032109/very-high-fan-speed-on-ubuntu-18-04)

I'm open to ideas and i would appreciate any help that can be provided :)

Comment: You have to configure it in Ubuntu with PWM.  This may help with configuring PWM https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032109/very-high-fan-speed-on-ubuntu-18-04/1034036#1034036 though it may use a different driver.  The temperature spikes are normal because the thermometer is right on the CPU.  I have water cooling and if I max the CPU the temp will hit 60C even though the liquid is 30C.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be able to detect any even though most of my fans are connected with a 4 pin connector and the ones that are with 3 pins are connected to a hub. This is the output of pwmconfig `/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed` and from sensors-detect : `Monitoring programs won't work until the needed modules are
loaded. You may want to run '/etc/init.d/kmod start'
to load them.` but kmod is running. Well i can control them trough the BIOS so i'll leave it at that but its strange and i'm wondering if its something from the MB.

Comment: post the output of `sensors-detect`, particularly the section that says 'SuperIO'.  Pay attention to what the output is.  Sometimes it's something simple like Secure Boot is enabled, sometimes it sees the IO chip but doesn't know what to do with it, sometimes you can manually get around that.  You can usually tell from the output.

Comment: Hi here is the output of sensors-detect : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TmVF3hnP0zSb1bPM0HFJbXKMCht9y2sO/view?usp=sharing
and this is what it found on SuperIO `Found Nuvoton NCT6797D Super IO Sensors Success! (address 0xa20, driver nct6775)`

Comment: That is good news, you should be able to get the fan control to work.  Did you save the /etc/modules file at the end of the detection?  You should have nct6775 in there.  Have you added `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` to the grub config and deployed that?

Comment: Thank you very much i've added it to grub and nct6775 was already in /etc/modules (i've maybe added it previously) and now everything is detected and pwmconfig works.
Your help is greatly appreciated!!