# lm-sensors only detects CPU temperatures, despite runing sensors-detect and loading /etc/modules (Intel i7 7700k + Asus TUF Z270 Mark II)

Tags: fan, temperature, fancontrol, sensors, lm-sensors

I am trying to monitor the temperatures and fan speeds of my desktop PC (Intel i7-7700k + Asus TUF Z270 Mark II + GeForce GTX 1060) through `lm-sensors` but `sensors` only outputs CPU info. I run several times `sensors-detect`, answered YES to all the questions YES/no, loaded the corresponding modules in `/etc/modules` but nothing works.

The modules it seems that I have to load are `coretemp`, `nct6775` and `i2c-i801`. I put them in the `/etc/modules` file, restarted `kmod`, reboot the machine, all things, and nothing works. I only see the CPU temps when running `sensors`. This is the output:

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +43.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +38.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +40.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +39.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +39.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

Nothing more. Nothing related to fans, to PCH temperature, motherboard, anything.

Does anyone know what is wrong and can help me please?

Thank you very much

Comment: Depending on the computer, that might be all the sensors on it.  Have a couple older Acers that is all they had, have a better Dell and have quite a few temp sensors and fan control.  Add your computer model and make to your question, and someone can tell you more.

Comment: It is a desktop PC Intel i7-7700k on an Asus TUF Z270 Mark II motherboard. I will put it in the question also

Comment: Would think that would have more sensors, but need someone that has one to tell you more.

Comment: It does. In windows I have info about PHC and motherboard temperature sensors, and 4 fan speeds.

Comment: This link has some ideas to help.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1145968/how-to-see-all-my-fans-in-sensors

Comment: Yes I saw it. Adding `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` to grub cmd line solves the problem, but it also seems that exposes the system to some inestabilities. It is a temporal fix, but not the solution to the problem :(

Comment: Will need someone else with more knowledge to jump in now.  Found that with google.

Comment: Can you be specific on the instabilities?  That setting just allows drivers to access resources that are claimed by ACPI, which is needed to access the Nuvoton chip.  I have a similar board and do not have any issues with this setting.